# How to match a term if it is in a list

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Below is my code, but where it says "CODE HERE" I want to match certain cities which would be the input with cities in a list.

So for example, if a city which is in the list is run through the function, I want it to output the city with "city" on the end. Possible?

Of course there are roughly 40 cities that should be in the list but I have not included them.

```
let listStackOverFlowExample = ["Kansas","Iowa"]


let cityAddCity (city:string) =
    | CODE HERE -> 
         city + " City"
```

Comment: Have you looked at Active Patterns?

Comment: No, but there has to be a simple one line code to do this and I have to use matching

Comment: Can you show man an example of how I would do that here?

Comment: `["Kansas","Iowa"]` looks like a mistake - you probably wanted to do `["Kansas"; "Iowa"]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a `when` clause with `List.contains` to determine whether the input city is in the list. Sample code:

```
let listStackOverFlowExample = ["Kansas"; "Iowa"]

let cityAddCity (city : string) =
    match city with
    | s when List.contains s listStackOverFlowExample -> sprintf "%s City" s
    | _  -> sprintf "%s is not in the list" city // Replace accordingly
```

Test code:

```
printfn "%s" <| cityAddCity "Kansas"
printfn "%s" <| cityAddCity "Tokyo"
```

Output:

```
Kansas City 
Tokyo is not in the list
```

Comment: Side note: Avoid using the `<|` operator like this. It makes the code much less readable because you first have to sort out the precedence to make sense of it. Don Syme himself advises to avoid using it wherever possible. `"Kansas" cityAddCity |> printfn "%s"` is a much more natural flow, and even `printfn "%s" (cityAddCity "Kansas")` is clearer to read (although to me the forward piped version better represents what's happening).

Comment: Sure @TeaDrivenDev

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation with an Active Pattern. It's identical to Samantha's, except that the `when` guard is moved out of the match expression. It doesn't have a big advantage in this case, but when you have a bigger number of cases to check for, it can clean up the match expression significantly by moving the details elsewhere (while also making them reusable).

```
let listStackOverFlowExample = ["Kansas"; "Iowa"]

let (|InList|_|) list item =
    if list |> List.contains item then Some item else None

let cityAddCity (city : string) =
    match city with
    | InList listStackOverFlowExample city  -> sprintf "%s City" city
    | _  -> sprintf "%s is not in the list" city // Replace accordingly
```